# jQuery submit form on checkbox press

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form on checking or unchecking a checkbox using jQuery and using the data value of that checkbox, can someone help me on how to do this?

Comment: if you post the HTML somebody may be able to help. I think this is a pretty simple problem, but you may want to describe more about what you want to happen.

Comment: I just have a list of checkboxes with a data value, each time a checkbox is checked I want to submit the form along with the value associated with that checkbox so I can use the data.

Comment: Why is this tagged ajax?

Comment: I assume he wants to use ajax to submit it

Comment: If you submit the form, the values of all checked checkboxes will be included in the submission. Are you saying that you also want the un-checking of a box to cause the form to be submitted, and to include the value of the box you just unchecked?

Comment: Yes Ken, that is what I am after. Both checking and unchecking of a box submitting the value of said box.

Comment: Wild guess here, but `$('#myCheckbox').change(function(){ $(this).closest('form').submit(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement of submitting the value of the box you just un-checked is the unusual bit here. One option is to stuff that value into a hidden field, which will be submitted. So:

```
<input name="checkbox_trigger" id="checkbox_trigger" value="" type="hidden" />
```

Then:

```
$('#yourcheckbox').click( function(e){
  $('#checkbox_trigger').val( e.value ); // capture on check or uncheck
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

If the name of the checkbox is also significant, you can easily follow this pattern to capture the field name as well.

Comment: `.change` may be a better fit than `.click`, unless it's always going to be triggered by the user's mouse.

Comment: My checkboxs' name is "checked_items[]", but the array is causing a syntax error. How can I work around this?

Comment: Brad, I agree that is a consideration. The reason I use `click` is that IE's behavior with checkbox events is buggy. Specifically: the `change` event is registered when the checked state changes *and* the checkbox is blurred -- meaning the change doesn't register until the focus moves elsewhere. There is a workaround using the `propertychange` event, but I didn't want to go too far down the rabbit hole to answer a relatively simple question.

Comment: @Neutralise, without seeing your specific code, I'd guess you need to escape the brackets with backslashes.

Comment: @Neutralise, that is part of the problem. I updated your pastebin: http://pastebin.com/P13wVrzB. First, `#` means selecting by ID. You're apparently trying to select by name. If you must do it that way, you not only must escape the brackets, but change your selector entirely: `$('form input[name="checked_items\\[\\]"]').click(...)`. I've also added a method to your form. Finally, must you use such an old version of jQuery? Try the current version.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try using .trigger

i think there is a trigger submit

```
$('#yourElement').live('click', function(){
    $('#yourForm').trigger('submit');
})
```